# Meteor Authenticate/Add Users with LDAP (or no password)

Tags: authentication, meteor, ldap, meteor-accounts

**EDIT: I've created and published a meteor package that integrates the ldapjs node package see [accounts-ldap](https://atmospherejs.com/typ/accounts-ldap)**

Feel free to submit any issues or pull requests on the [github page](https://github.com/typ90/meteor-accounts-ldap/)

**Original question:**
Users are authenticated through ldap and I've created a custom login handler that works properly against ldap (Accounts.registerLoginHandler(...)).

Currently, I need to import user accounts on startup. Because I'm using ldap as a 3rd party to authenticate, I won't be able to store passwords for the users. I'm wondering how I can hook in to validate user logins without storing the password.

So the real question is:
**How can I authenticate users on login without having a password?**

Answer (score 0):

You can autenticate to ldap get user id/name check exist in meteor users than can impersonate that user using:
(In a server method)

```
this.setUserId(userId);
```

Where `userId` is imported meteor `userid`.